# How to solve " Module not found: 'readline'" in Node project

Tags: node.js

I am using create-react-app to build a Node project.

And I have used `npm -i --save-dev sat-words` to install a module called `sat-words`. However when I run the project it tells me

`Module not found: 'readline' ...`

In `sat-words`'s `index.js` file it uses `readline` to read a text file, like this:

```
var rl = require('readline').createInterface({
    input: require('fs').createReadStream(__dirname + '/word-list.txt')
  });
```

But in Node.js documentation `readline` is a core module. Why would it throw an error saying the module is not found at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

If you put your program `index.js` in the same directory as your `package.json`, you should be able to run it with `node index.js`.

For instance, if your program (`index.js`) is

```
var SATWords = require('sat-words');
SATWords.getWords(function(words){
      console.log(words)
})
```

it will print out all the words when you run `node index.js`.

Comment: The create-react-app put all js files in `src` folder. And I use `npm start` command to run the program.